# Initializing AudioDeviceManager in JUCE Audio App

Tags: c++, xcode, juce

I am trying to initialize the instance of AudioDeviceManager, in the constructor of my MainContentComponent:

`MainContentComponent(): deviceManager (getSharedAudioDeviceManager())`

where

```
  AudioDeviceManager& getSharedAudioDeviceManager()  
     {  

 if (sharedAudioDeviceManager == nullptr)

    {
        sharedAudioDeviceManager = new AudioDeviceManager();
        sharedAudioDeviceManager->initialise (2, 2, 0, true, String::empty, 0);
    }

    return *sharedAudioDeviceManager;
}
```

and my declarations would be:

`AudioDeviceManager& deviceManager;
static ScopedPointer<AudioDeviceManager> sharedAudioDeviceManager;`

There are no compile errors, but I have runtime errors, wherein the compiler tells me:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MainContentComponent::sharedAudioDeviceManager", referenced from:
      MainContentComponent::getSharedAudioDeviceManager() in MainComponent.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Totally lost. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your static member outside of the class declaration, like this...

```
ScopedPointer<AudioDeviceManager> MainContentComponent::sharedAudioDeviceManager;
```

Also, this is a **linktime** error, not a **runtime** error.

Comment: thank you for the correction! it worked when i defined it the same way, but without the static keyword, also within the MainContentComponent class.

Comment: Yes that would work to, but it'd also change the meaning of the program. If this answer helped you, could you please mark it as accepted? :)